# htaccess rename mp3 on the fly

Tags: htaccess

I want all mp3 files residing on my server to have "-xxx" added at the end of the filename when a user downloads them. Example:

file on the server: file.mp3

when user downloads: file-xxx.mp3

I've googled something that is pretty close to what I want:

https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/htaccess-rename-mp3.128317/

As I don't want to be limited to any particular folder, and would like to have all .mp3's renamed on the fly, I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ([^.]+)-by-domain\.mp3$ $1.mp3 [L]
```

but for some reason I can't get it to work, files don't get renamed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: RewriteRules don't "rename" files, they edit instead edit the request so the file being served can be found. So, the client won't be accessing `file.mp3`, the client will be accessing `file-xxx.mp3`, and the RewriteRule will simply allow the file named `file.mp3` to be returned as the requested filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked when tested on my server

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)-([0-9]+).mp3 /$1.mp3
```

It works as follows - The RewriteRule is broken up into 4 parts,

1. the prefix including the path and first part of the name of the file
2. the "-"
3. the numbers in the file
4. the end part of the file (.mp3)

The script takes only the prefix from the original file - the part ^/(.*) and then rebuilds this into a new url (the $1 contains the part between the brackets in the part above).

The ([0-9]+) detects the unique number, so if you are wanting to do something more fancy later on you could write (for example) a PHP script which allows the user to download the file, and logs information about it by changing the rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)-([0-9]+).mp3 /path/process.php?mp3=$1&userid=$2
```

(You would need to write the php script as well of-course, but the example above shows the logic as to how the rewrite rule processes the URL into parts.)